# Getting .NET Core stack traces on Linux without suspending the process

Tags: linux, debugging, .net-core, lldb, sos

On Windows [Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime (ClrMd)](https://github.com/Microsoft/clrmd) allows "attaching" to a .NET process (including .NET Core) without really attaching a debugger and gettings the stack traces of all its managed threads without suspending it. Is there a way to do this on Linux with .NET Core 2.1?

I know LLDB with libsosplugin.so can be used to get stack traces, but that suspends the process, sometimes for several minutes, which makes it unusable in a production scenario.

Comment: [windows has APIs sind 8.1 to clone/Snapshot processes](https://github.com/mjsabby/CopyOnWriteDump/blob/master/Program.cs) and analyze them. Look if there is something similar in Linux.